# How the center of mass of a tree is important in holding its structure?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, classical-mechanics

How weak roots and wind affect the center of mass? We know when roots are no longer strong, they cannot support the tree anymore, thus the tree topples. But how can I relate the center of mass or center of gravity to this?

Answer (score 1):

The reason strong roots help trees to not topple is not so much because of the center of mass. It is because of the mechanical support they provide the trees because of getting deep into the soil .

The more the roots are "dug in" into the soil, the more of a counterbalancing torque is provided by the ground, when high winds start to provide a torque on the top part of the tree .